# How does the command structure of the Machines work?

Tags: the-matrix, artificial-intelligence, politics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of a political hierarchy do the machines in The Matrix have?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12725/what-kind-of-a-political-hierarchy-do-the-machines-in-the-matrix-have)

While discussing why the Sentinels in *The Matrix: Revolutions* would participate in a suicide mission, [DVK pointed out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/19056/2565#comment35437_19058) that there might be (military) repercussions if they didn't follow command.

Is it really that simple? How is the command structure of the machines organised? If there is any.
Individual machines seem to have an independent conciousness, as seen in *The Animatrix*, so they're not one big Borg-like conciousness. This would imply an (at least technical) distinction between egoism and altruism for a given individual (machine).

*Note: A mere explanation why the sentinels broke the walls of Zion, will **NOT** be a sufficient answer to this question. I'm asking about the overall organisation of their culture/military.*

Comment: Clearly when Sentinels die they get revived at the nearest Resurrection ship.

Comment: @JackBNimble: What universe is this a reference to?

Comment: @bitmask I think it is a joke about the Battlestar Galactica universe :)